# How could I make this XSLT not(contains()) work?

Tags: xml, xslt

I put here this part of the XSLT with the `if`:

```
<xsl:template match="receta">
<xsl:if test="./ingredientes/ingrediente[not(contains(., 'Leche'))] and 
              ./ingredientes/ingrediente[not(contains(., 'Queso'))] ">
    <article>
        <header>
            <h2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="nombre"/>
```

And the corresponding part of the XML:

```
<receta n="R2">
    <nombre>
        Croquetas de bacalao
    </nombre>
    <tipo>
        Primer plato
    </tipo>
    <ingredientes>
        <ingrediente cantidad= "1" unidad="en lomos">
            Bacalao
        </ingrediente>
        <ingrediente cantidad= "850" unidad= "ml.">
            Leche entera
        </ingrediente>
```

Without the `not()` it works but obviously it's not what I need. Which is the correct way of using `not()` in this case?

Comment: You need to explain which result you are looking for. What is the condition you want to check, which `receta`s do you want to match in your template?

Comment: I want to get the recipes without the substring of the if as an ingredient

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to test if a single `ingrediente` does not contain both substrings, then change

```
<xsl:if test="./ingredientes/ingrediente[not(contains(., 'Leche'))] and 
              ./ingredientes/ingrediente[not(contains(., 'Queso'))]">
```

to

```
<xsl:if test="ingredientes/ingrediente[not(contains(., 'Leche')) and
                                       not(contains(., 'Queso'))]">
```

otherwise two separate `ingrediente` can separately not contain each substring.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to test if none of the ingredients contain Lecho or Quese. That would be

```
test="not(./ingredientes/ingrediente[contains(., 'Leche'))] and 
      not(./ingredientes/ingrediente[contains(., 'Queso'))]"
```

Your code is testing that there is at least one ingredient which doesn't contain Leche and at least one that doesn't contain Queso, which I don't think is going to satisfy people allergic to dairy products.

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable `ingredientes` like below :

```
<xsl:template match="receta">
   <xsl:variable name="ingredientes">
      <xsl:value-of select="./ingredientes/ingrediente"/>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:if test="not(contains($ingredientes, 'Leche')) and not(contains($ingredientes, 'Queso')) ">
    <article>
        <header>
            <h2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="nombre"/>
```